# SQL query returns null values when written to file in groovy

Tags: sql, groovy, oracle11g

I am attempting to export data and write to a formatted file in groovy 2.1.6. The query returns a null value for an entire column included in the query.

```
    null, 0000001,1434368,ACTIVE
    null, 0000002,1354447,ACTIVE
    null, 0000004,1358538,ACTIVE
```

Here is the code that I am using in Groovy to query and write the data to a file.

```
private void profilerSql() {
    def today = new Date()
    def formattedDate = today.format('yyyyMMdd')
    String reportSql
    reportSql = """
        SELECT
            col_1,
            col_2,
            col_3,
            col_4
        from my_table
        """
    sql.execute(reportSql)

    def filename = "My_Table_export_" + formattedDate + ".csv"

    //Create the file Object
    File outputFile = new File(filename);

    //Write a blank line to it to create a new "empty" file
    outputFile.write("");

    // Iterate through the SQL recordset. Output settings are defined within the function.
    sql.eachRow(reportSql) {


        // Create each line, joining the columns with a comma.

        def reportLine = [it.col_1, it.col_2, it.col_3, it.col_4].join(',')

        // Write the line to the file. End with a new line char.
        outputFile.append(reportLine + System.getProperty("line.separator"))
    }

}
```

Perhaps relevant information, the column that returns null values was created as a sequence in Oracle 11g. If any one can provide some insight even into how Groovy interacts with different data types in Oracle databases I would be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

I see a couple things questionable about the code but none of which are about getting a sequence column out of Oracle - but wouldn't really expect that to be much of a problem - since JDBC has been around for years and years.

1. Don't think you need the initial call to sql.execute(reportSql) - the execute returns a boolean rather than a resultset.
2. Shouldn't the first parm to the outputFile.append be reportLine and not lineFormat?

Hope this helps!

Comment: Good catch with the reportLine. It should be report line but it making the code anonymous I forgot to change that piece. Thanks for pointing out that the sql.execute() statement is redundant or even inappropriate. Looking closer at the groovy documentation sql.eachrow() is sufficient. [Groovy Docs](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Tutorial+6+-+Groovy+SQL)